# Change the sizes in portrait mode for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus

Tags: iphone, ios8, landscape-portrait, size-classes

Size classes :

compact width any height
for all compact width layout (all phones except iPhone 6 plus)

compact width regular height
for all iphone in potrait

any width compact height
for all iphone in landscape (except iphone 6 plus)

regular width compact height (for iPhone 6 plus)
iphone 6 plus in landscape

**Now i have label and i change the font size for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus e.g for "compact width any height" its "12" and for "compact width regular height" its "15" in portrait . the size is 15 for all iPhones in portrait**.

**But it is all right in landscape when i change the font size of "any width compact height"  to "12" and "regular width compact height" to "15" its working fine .**

My Question is that how should i do the same for portrait ???

Comment: Did the answer fix the problem?

Comment: yes it helps me to figure out some problem

Comment: I think this is useful but that is not the full answer which i want so for your support +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt" size:49.0]];
```

Set the font size now i calculate the size with respect to ratio .

As we know iPhone 5 is 85.3 % smaller than iPhone 6 so after some research...

```
if (IS_IPHONE_6)
        [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:self.font.fontName size:(self.font.pointSize)*1.18]];
        else if (IS_IPHONE_5)
        {
        [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:self.font.fontName size:(self.font.pointSize)]];
        }
        else
        {
            [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:self.font.fontName size:(self.font.pointSize)*1.3]];

        }
```

This will solve my problem ......

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to set up requirements for each orientation.  However, the UI adapts to a size class, not to an orientation.

Don't think of size classes in terms of orientation.

Try this:

- wAny hAny: font size 15
- wAny hCompact: font size 12
- wCompact hAny: font size 12

This should use 12 if it is Compact|Compact, Regular|Compact, or Compact|Regular, and 15 otherwise.

Comment: But size classes do change depending on the orientation. You cannot ignore orientation because the size classes you get will depend on orientation. Example: All iPhones are Regular height in Portrait, but only the 6 Plus is Regular width when in landscape, the smaller iPhones are Compact width in Portrait. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html